# PDE on a Damped Wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What are the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $$ X''+X'-\sigma X=0 \\ \text{ with boundary condition } X(0)=X(l)=0$$

I know that for $X''-\sigma X=0 $, the eigenvalues would be $ -\left ( \frac{n \pi}{l} \right )^2$ and the eigenfunction would be $ X= \ sin(n \pi x/l)$

Just not sure how to deal with the additional X' in my problem.

Comment: look for solutions having the form $X(x) = A e^{kx}$

Answer (score 2):

A way to solve for the eigenvalues $\sigma$ is to first solve
$$
                     X''+X'-\sigma X =0\\
                     X(0)=0,\;\; X'(0)=1.
$$

- The solution of this equation is unique. You should have studied such equations by now. You can factor the equation into operator form with $D=\frac{d}{dx}$:
  $$
                    \{(D+1/2)^{2}-(1/4+\sigma)\}X = 0 \\
                       (D+1/2-\sqrt{1/4+\sigma})(D+1/2+\sqrt{1/4+\sigma})X=0.
  $$
  The solutions are
  $$
                       X(x)=A\exp(\{-1/2+\sqrt{1/4+\sigma}\}x)+B\exp(\{-1/2-\sqrt{1/4+\sigma}\}x)
  $$
  You get $X(0)=0$ with $A+B=0$. You get $X'(0)=1$ with
  $$
       A(-1/2+\sqrt{1/4+\sigma})+B(-1/2-\sqrt{1/4+\sigma})=1.
  $$
  Assuming $A+B=0$ then gives $(A-B)\sqrt{1/4+\sigma}=1$.
  The desired constants are
  $$
              A=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1/4+\sigma}},\;\; B=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1/4+\sigma}}.
  $$
  Therefore,
  $$
              X(x) = \frac{e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{1/4+\sigma}}\sinh(\sqrt{1/4+\sigma}x),\;\; \sigma \ne -1/4.
  $$

An advantage of using a normalized $X$ is that the special case where $\sigma=-1/4$ is handled by taking a limit of the above as $\sigma\rightarrow-1/4$: this gives $xe^{-x/2}$, which is the proper solution for $\sigma=-1/4$. (The special case being handled by a limit is guaranteed by the general theory when you used normalized functions.) This special case where $\sigma=-1/4$ is not $0$ at $l$, which allows us to rule out $\sigma=-1/4$ as a possible eigenvalue.

Any function $Y$ for which $Y''+Y'-\sigma Y=0$ and $Y(0)=0$ must be a constant multiple of the above solution. So finding a non-zero solution of $Y(0)=Y(l)=0$ is equivalent to finding $\sigma$ so that $X(l)=0$ for the above $X$ because $Y$ must be a non-zero constant multiple of $X$ by uniqueness of $X$. $\sinh$ is not $0$ at $l$, but it switches to $\sin$ if the argument is complex. So $\sigma < -1/4$ must hold, and the possible values of $\sigma$ must satisfy
$$
       \sqrt{1/4+\sigma} = in\pi/l \\
       \implies 1/4+\sigma = -n^{2}\pi^{2}/l^{2} \\
       \implies \sigma = -\frac{1}{4}-\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{l^{2}},\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
This is what Juan had posted and deleted. It's worth seeing how to do this kind of thing at least once.